# Sitecore using Dynamics CRM - which permission level does the user used in ConnectionStrings needs to have?

Tags: security, module, dynamics-crm-module

I have a Sitecore instance using Dynamics CRM within the follow ConnectionStrings.config

```
<add name="Dynamics-2011" connectionString="url=http://crmdevvm:5555/crmdev/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc; user id=domain\Myaccount;password=P@ssw0rd;organization=crmdev;authentication type=0" />
```

As this is a development environment, the user **MyAccount** has **System Administrator** permission (Security Role) in CRM.

Now, this needs to go to Production and I wonder which permission level would be necessary to keep things up & running without messing up with the communication between Sitecore and CRM.

Comment: Do you use the Dynamics CRM online on-premises?

Comment: It is on-premises, sorry I should gave you that information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for Sitecore to be able to access account information from CRM, the CRM user used to connect to CRM must have the following permissions assigned:

- Read account entities

If these permissions are not assigned, an error will occur when Sitecore tries to read data from CRM.

Comment: You've asked about online or on-premises, right? What would be the difference in case I am running in cloud?

Comment: Yes, I asked. But then I have investigated this and I think it doesn't matter which type of Dynamics CRM you use.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich did you get this info from Sitecore site?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Yes. We can find that by the following link: http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DynamicsCrmConnect/v1.1/cookbooks/supporting-additional-crm-entities/simple-synchronization/confirm-crm-privileges.html